# Tree View Open it's respective Div in the right side

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have downloaded a Tree View Code and it is working fine. The code is in this way :

```
d = new dTree('d');

        d.add(0,-1,'StratApps');
        d.add(1,0,'First Folder','example.html');

        d.add(2,1,'Packages','example1.html');
        d.add(3,2,'Pkg_Load_Dim','example2.html');
        d.add(4,2,'Pkg_Write_to_File','#');

        d.add(5,1,'Interfaces','#');
        d.add(6,5,'Int_Load_Order_Dim','#');
        d.add(7,5,'Int_Load_Channel_Dim','#');

        d.add(8,1,'Procedures','#');
        d.add(9,8,'Proc_Update_Order','#');
        d.add(10,8,'Proc_Process_Errors','#');

        document.write(d);
```

Now I want to give the links to open respective Divs in the right-side. Can anyone help me in this regard...

Comment: From which library is this tree from? Post a link, so we can help

Comment: I have downloaded it from this site : http://www.destroydrop.com/javascripts/tree/                                                    In the top right side u can see dtree.zip to download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something along these lines:

```
$('.dtree a.node').prop('onclick', '').click(function(e) {
    var href = $(this).prop('href');
    $('#divOnRightSide').load(href);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Basically, what you say is: for every node (i.e. link) there is in every dtree on the page, remove the onClick-event directly from the HTML and add a click event handler.
In this handler, get the href-attr, and load the content of that link into the div with id="divOnRightSide".
Then, so no page navigation is triggered, use e.preventDefault().

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Here is a jsFiddle to demonstrate the purpose: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7nAN/1/).

Comment: It's opening in New Window, I want the content should show Right-side in the same page.

Comment: with your given code I have modified, but still it's opening in a new window. Can u please, download the Left-Panel from this site : destroydrop.com/javascripts/tree and show me in http://jsfiddle.net/ so that, I will get the clear one... Please.

Comment: Sorry to kept you waiting! A fully working jsFiddle is now available. Good luck.

Comment: sorry to say you, once it worked and now it's not working in jsFiddle. Please, check once...

Comment: It seems that this tree is doing something else then... But maybe it's just a jsFiddle bug. Have you tried running it offline with some sample files? If yes and it still doesn't work, I can't help you further :(

Comment: thank u very much for your support. I will try further to get the best